# Non greedy regexp eat too much

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

i have a string

```
<div class="line"><input name="sid" value="" type="hidden"><img src="1.jpg" height="40" width="180"><input name="word" size="30" maxlength="50" value="" type="text"></div>
```

and i trying to find and replace whole input with name = word, with this regexp:

```
/<input .+?word.+?>/ui
```

preg_match returns this:

```
array (
  0 => '<input name="sid" value="" type="hidden"><img src="1.jpg" alt="CAPTCHA" height="40" width="180"><input name="word" size="30" maxlength="50" value="" type="text">',
)
```

please help me to write working regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one: `/<input[^>]+name="word".+?>/ui`

In your pattern it finds first `<input` and then until `word`...
If you use `<input[^>]+` it will find `<input` and than group of simbols except closing  `>` until `name="word"`.

Comment: You still have a greedy match there.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-*

Comment: @AleksandrBannov please check the best answer if you think it so

Answer (score 0):

Use this one: `/<input ([^>]+)?name=['"]?word['"]?([^>]+)?>/ui`